# Is calling qt udpsocket flush useful?

Tags: c++, qt, qudpsocket

I am using the QUdpSocket to write reference data to a robot.
I hope the transmission could be as real time as possible.
Here is what I am doing now:

```
if (dataBuffer.count() > 0)
{
    int numWritten = udp_socket->writeDatagram(dataBuffer.left(64), t_host, t_port);
    if (numWritten > 0) { dataBuffer.remove(0, numWritten); }
}
```

A timer is triggering the above code at 50Hz.
Is it necessary to call `flush` in this case after the writeDatagram call?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not necessary to call `flush()`. The `writeDatagram` method has instantaneous effect. Make sure that the timer you're using is a `Qt::PreciseTimer`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the system. But flush can be used to make sure it will write as soon as possible. In some system using  waitForBytesWritten() is enough.

Comment: Someone down voted this without comment, so it may be appropriate to discuss waitForBytesWritten() ... waitForBytesWritten() is useful only for connected UDP sockets. The documentation says that writeDatagram should be sufficient, but the object does have a flush() function.